# How do I make Resharper respect capitals in camelcase code completion?

Tags: resharper, code-completion, camelcasing

In ReSharper 5.1 running on VS 2008, I am trying to complete a method name using CamelHumps with the following code:

```
public bool debugMode { get; private set; }
public DebugWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void logOutput(List<String> logLines)
{
    foreach(string line in logLines)
    {
        <- cursor is here
    }
}

public void logOutput(String logLine)
{
    debugTextBox.Text += "\n" + logLine;
}
```

At the above-noted cursor point I type `lO` and hit Ctrl+Space.  I want it to present me with a prompt for the `logOutput(String)` method, but instead it presents me with a prompt for `logLines` with the one I want displayed underneath in the dropdown box.  If I instead type `lOu` it gives me the correct prompt highlighted (same with `lou`), but I think I should be able to just type `lO` and it should work.  I have CamelHumps checked under Resharper->Options->Editor.  I also have hotkeys set to the Resharper defaults, rather than the VS ones.

I know this behavior existed in IntelliJ in the past, but this issue has irritated me ever since starting with ReSharper.

Is there something else I need to have selected/set in the options? Is this even possible in ReSharper?

I tried searching for other similar questions, but I've only seen comments/questions on the all lower case completion or camel case selection.

**Edit:** Note that both `logOutput` methods are present in the list of options for completion, but it's not selecting them as the completion to be inserted when I hit Enter. I would have to type additional characters to force it to choose one of them.  So the issue is, previously in IntelliJ `lO` was sufficient to make it select `logOutput` as the one to be inserted because of the capital O; is that possible in ReSharper, and if so how?

Comment: I copied the two *logOutput* methods in a test class and inserted line `TextBox debugTextBox = new TextBox();` to second mehod to avoid compiling errors. And it works: both *logOutput* methods are shown in completion list after typing `lO`. I have ReSharper 5.1.3000.12 and VS 2010.

Comment: Yeah, they do show up in the completion list for me as well, but you either have to type additional characters to prompt it to choose `logOutput()` as the selected option, or use the arrow keys to move down to the method.  With IntelliJ `lO`, the O being capitalized, was enough to tell it that it should reduce the options to possibilities with a lower case `l` and uppercase `O`.  However, since it thinks that `logLines` is the primary choice in this case, it's not paying attention to the capitalization of the O that I typed.

I'll edit the question to reflect that they're in the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you are not getting the expected result is because of the name of the `logLines` variable. Because the first 2 letters of that variable are `lo`, it takes precedence over any CamelCase match. So i guess there must be some logic in Resharpers matching system that favours sequential characters over CamelCase matches.

For example, if you change the name of `logOutput` to something like `storeOutput` and then you type `sO` it will show you the prompt you expect (proving that CamelCase matching is working).

I've never used IntelliJ, but i expect it was probably the same logic in that, you just didn't notice because you didn't have clashing variable names.

You could always just hit the down arrow after `Alt+Space` to bring up the prompts for `logOutput(...)`. That would get you the results you want and is only a single extra keypress.

Comment: I'm certain I've had conflicting names in IntelliJ in the past and using the capital letters to refine results has worked.  I'm starting to think that this kind of completion refinement simply doesn't exist in ReSharper, which is a pity. It's true I can get the method I want with additional keypresses, but that's what I'm trying to avoid with the uppercase, if the functionality were there. For instance, if I changed the name, typing `so` all lowercase would get me the same result, rendering the capital `O` irrelevant/useless.

Comment: @neromir yeah, you might be right. Like i say, i've not used IntelliJ, so i can't be sure.

Comment: Actually, correction to my above comment: the `O` in uppercase does present some refinement in the case of renaming to `storeOutput`.  If I type all lowercase it presents me with other stuff not in the class's scope.  It seems, however, that with variable/method names closer in relevance (e.g. in my class), the uppercaseness is ignored.

Comment: @neromir it sounds pretty confusing... the best you can hope for is to learn Resharper's quirks and at best tame it into submission. To be fair, its multitude of other useful features make it worth it :)

Comment: @neromir also, have you tried using resharpers "Go to file member" shortcut Alt + \ ? That might be better for you?

Comment: That is a useful function that makes use of the capital `O`.  I'd have to copy/paste the name from there, so at that point the extra keystrokes in the regular code completion is better for workflow.  But, thanks for pointing that out anyway. I wasn't aware of it before you mentioned it. Also, I wish I could mod your answer up, despite the fact that I don't think it's the correct answer, I think it was very useful.

Comment: actually, after re-reading your first paragraph I think your answer is probably more accurate to what's actually happening in ReSharper's behavior.  I think I'll leave my answer below for anyone looking for what the JetBrains people said.

Answer (score 0):

After waiting a few days for additional responses here, I went ahead and posted the question on the ReSharper forums over at JetBrains along with a link back here.  The short answer is that it's not possible in ReSharper 5.1 and up.

For the full answer text, see: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5455545